# Help identify a book featuring a Stone Age biological attack

Tags: story-identification

I read a book in the early 1980s (I think, though maybe a bit later) which was set in the Stone Age (approximately) in Southern England.

At one point the hero is enslaved and put to work in a mine named "The Trundle" under the South Downs (chalk hills along the south east coast of England), iirc.

Later, he wreak revenge on someone by laying a trap baited with a deadly biological toxin (maybe ergot) which the villain obligingly falls for, ingests and dies a suitably gruesome death.  I think there was some blurb on the back that mentioned that it contains Britain's earliest biological attack.

I imagine the author was British.  I think the paperback (which was larger format than Penguins, etc.) was published by one of the publishers who specialised at the time in modern authors, e.g. Picador.

Does anyone recognise this story?

Comment: Are there any science fiction or fantasy elements to the work?

Comment: @SeanDuggan:  Good question.  TBH, I posted it here because I mentally categorized  it as science fiction (or maybe I mean faction) , and I've no idea how far a story has to depart from known prehistory (if at all) to constitute "fantasy"

Comment: I figured someone was going to ask eventually. :) Haven't found the book for you yet. Closest I've found is a book set in prehistoric South Downs, "The Amulet of Tarv: A Romance of the South Downs 1,000 Years B. C." although I've yet to find the text.

Comment: @SeanDuggan:  Fwiw, I spent an hour or two trawling "find story from plot" sites with zero success before posting here.  And until I mislaid it, it was definitely on one of my SF shelves ;=)

Comment: @SeanDuggan It's set in the Stone Age, that makes it science fiction. [Prehistoric](http://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/prehistoric_sf) stories are a part of science fiction, just as much as postapocalyptics, interplanetaries, lab stories, and the rest.

Comment: I believe this would be the real-world "Trundle" in question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trundle_(hill_fort) Not sure if that helps.

Comment: And just after finding that, I found a strong candidate for the work in question: https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/richard-herley/the-flint-lord/ But I can't find any mentions online of poisoning with ergot in _The Flint Lord_

Comment: @SeanDuggan:  Thanks but I'm fairly sure it wasn't The Amulet, because I'd remember owning a book with a name like "Tarv" in the title.

Comment: @recognizer:  Thanks, I think you're onto something with Richard Herley because the name is definitely familiar.  I think the book I was thinking of is actually the first book in his Flint Lord series, The Stone Arrow.  I'm just skimming the free Kindle edition and it certainly mentions the Trundle and I've found an poisoning episode using Death's Cap mushrooms, which may well have got mixed up with ergot in my memory and would explain my inability to find it myself.  The Amazon reviews chime with what I remember, too.  So, put Herley/Stone Arrow  up as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Perhaps one of the downvoters would care to elaborate?

Comment: @recognizer how 'bout posting that as an answer now? :) (see OP comment above)